# Transforming cartesian unit vectors to polar coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Consider the transformation matrix from cartesian $(x,y)$ to polar $(R,\phi)$ coordinates:

\begin{equation}\left[ \frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^b} \right]=
\begin{bmatrix} 
\cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) \\
-\frac{1}{R}\sin(\phi) & \frac{1}{R}\cos(\phi) 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where the primed coordinates are the polar coordinates.
To transform the unit vector $\hat e_x=(1,0)$ to polar coordinates, using $x'^a=\frac{\partial x'^a}{\partial x^b}x^b$, will lead me to:
$\hat e_x=\cos(\phi)\hat e_R-\frac{1}{R}\sin(\phi)\hat e_\phi$, which isn't correct, due to the $\frac{1}{R}$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not wrong. It's totally correct. Your choice of $\hat{e}_{\phi}$ (implicit in the Jacobian, as you used the function $\phi$ and not the function $R\phi$) makes its norm proportional to $R$, hence the normalising coefficient $\frac{1}{R}$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! After a while I calculated $R$ for which $|\hat e_x|$ is  1 and, indeed, $R = 1$ if I'm correct.

Comment: Ah, yes. If your prefer to let $|e_r|=|e_\phi|=1$ then $e_x$ and $e_y$ will no longer be normalised, and only be so when $r=1$.

Comment: Ahh I think I recall: the jacobian of this transformation, R, is the scale at which the transformation occurs so the norm of the cartesian unit vectors in polar coordinates will be scaled accordingly. Thank you!